# Understanding React Structure

Tags: reactjs, structure

I'm having a few issues understanding how react works. I have the below code, and am wondering where I can do stuff with the returned DataRows

```
function App() {
    const [DataRows, setDataRows] = useState([]);

    async function getPageData() {
        const ShowId =  window.location.pathname.split("/");
        const params = new URLSearchParams([['ShowId', ShowId[2]]]);
        const response = await axios.get(PAGE_DATA_URL, { params });
        setDataRows(response.data['DataRows']); 
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getPageData();
    }, []);

    // var counter = 0;

    if (!DataRows) { return "Loading"; }

    /* Do I put an else here to start using DataRows? The below code logs a bunch of zero's
    else {
        console.log(counter);
        counter++;
    }
    */
    return (
    // Or maybe here? Using DataRows to change state results in loops
    );
}
export default App;
```

**an example of DataRows is:**

```
{
  "DataRows":[{
        "ID": "EwE0NLOJNj",
        "DisplayOrder": "1",
        "DisplayDiv": "1",
        "RowType": "SponsorBanner",
        "SponsorBannerTextColor": "rgba(129, 129, 129,1)",
        "SponsorBannerBGColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
      },{
        "ID": "jrxTRD0aOO",
        "DisplayOrder": "1",
        "DisplayDiv": "2",
        "RowType": "AgendaMenu",
        "AgendaMenuTextColor": "rgba(129, 129, 129,1)",
        "AgendaMenuBGColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
        "AgendaMenuButtonBG": "rgba(96, 140, 96, 1)"
      },{
        "ID":"ImyftecmJE",
        "RowType": "Tab",
        "DisplayOrder": "1",
        "Label":"MONDAY"
      }
}
```

The RowType is the name of a react component. I iterate this object and save the component of the same name to an array based on where it goes on the page. The problem is I also need to change some state variables depending on this data, and if I do that in the return it creates loops.

So, what actually gets rendered here? I thought it was what was in the return()... but it's everything in App? Sorry for these likely silly questions, but nothing I can find explains what is actually going on in React.

Or do I do all the initial data stuff in index.js, and just pass what I need as props, ie,

```
<App DataRows={DataRows} />
```

Comment: `counter` is declared each render cycle, and when you log `counter` it is still the initial value, thus it will alway log `0`. What are you wanting, or trying, to do with the `DataRows` state? Either way, you should just use the return in the root scope of the function component body if you are not using the early return.

Comment: if you want to use the state in another component better to use contextApi

Answer (score 0):

```js
function App() {
    const [DataRows,setDataRows] = useState([]);
    const [counter,setCounter] = useState(1);

    async function getPageData() {
        const ShowId =  window.location.pathname.split("/");
        const params = new URLSearchParams([['ShowId', ShowId[2]]]);
        const response = await axios.get(PAGE_DATA_URL, { params });
        setDataRows(response.data['DataRows']); 
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getPageData();
    }, []);

    if (!DataRows) { 
    return "Loading"; 
    
    }else {
        console.log(counter);
        setCounter(counter++);
      }
    
    return (
    // if you need to print data you can use map() loop like     //this
    
    DataRows.map((datarow,index)=>{
    // if you need render any thing you can use mention below
    return(
    <tr key={index}>
    //if you need counter here also you render like this
    <td>{index+1}</td>
    //you need to print any thing you can use API parameters     //with datarow
          <td>{datarow.any Parameter you need to print from               API, you write with (datarow.)}
          </td>
    <tr>
    );
    })
    );
}
export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```